# How to get balanced accuracy from deep learning with Keras in R?

Tags: r, keras

I am using Keras package and tensorflow for binary classification by deep learning. At the end, the score function gives me accuracy by

```
    score <- model %>% evaluate(testing, testLabels, batch_size = 64)
```

My question is how can I obtain balanced accuracy for this algorithm?

Comment: Balanced as in weighted by class frequencies? Use the `sample_weight` argument. See [the documentation](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/evaluate.html.)

Comment: Thank you for your response, the website you put in here does not work.

Comment: Sorry, a trailing dot! [Fixed](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/evaluate.html). You can get the doc with `?evaluate` anyway.

Comment: Ok, the evaluate is what I wrote as a code in above and it gives me $acc.

Comment: If you provide sample weights to `evaluate` then `acc` will be the weighted accuracy.  Balanced accuracy is a particular case of weighted accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean additional metrics like balanced accuracy or mcc for example, you can do the folllowing :

```
eval_model <- model %>% evaluate(x_test , y_test )

pred_model <- model %>% predict_classes(x_test)

conf.matrix <-  caret::confusionMatrix(
factor(pred_model, levels = 0:1),
factor(y_test, levels = 0:1),
positive = "1"
```

)

```
BalancedAccuracy <- conf.matrix$byClass[11]
Accuracy <- conf.matrix$overall[1]
F1 <- conf.matrix$byClass[7]
#mathews correlation coefficent
MCC <- mccr(y_test,pred_model)
```